# Show entire ActionBar when using SlidingMenu library

Tags: android

Currently, I've implemented Jeremy Feinstein's slidingMenu in my app.  I want to introduce something new however.  When the device is a tablet, I want the sliding of the menu for the activity to be disabled and for the menu to always show alongside the content.  I am currently achieving this by calling slidingMenu.showMenu() in the onCreate of the activity only if it's running on a tablet and disabling slidingMenu.showContent().

The issue with this implementation for my use is that part of the actionBar is hidden (the settings button on the far right) whenever showMenu() is called, and thus always hidden on tablets.  Any suggestions as to how to approach the problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use official Android Navigation Drawer:
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
Secondly you can create different layout for tablet and for the phone. For example you can have navigation drawer in the phone layout and int the tablet layout just two linear layouts or something.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the navigation drawer, I had no idea this existed.  The second piece of advice you gave me was also good; I was just having a slow day it seems :) Thanks again!